# iPhone NSDateFormatter Timezone Conversion

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create a formatter that will convert the date format shown to an NSDate object:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2010-06-21T19:00:00-05:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

The issue is the timezone -05:00, which is not parsed properly with the format above. Any suggestions?

Comment: does your pattern really match the input?

Comment: The format is all good up to the timezone (-05:00). If I remove the ':' the formatter works. Trying to understand if there is a means to have a formatter that will properly parse the timezone as is.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094819/nsdateformatter-returning-nil-in-os-4-0/3968411#3968411

Comment: pueden ayudarme con estan pregunta 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162835/how-to-use-nsdateformatter-to-venezuela

gracias

Comment: User `NSISO8601DateFormatter` instead as suggested by [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Honestly, you'll just have to change the source data (removing the colon) before running it through the formatter. Your original date string is non-standard and none of the time zone format strings will work properly on it.

You can see the valid inputs [on unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

ZZZ e.g. "-0500"

ZZZZ e.g. "GMT-05:00"

Nothing for "-05:00"

Comment: After trying any number of approaches, that is what I settled on as well. Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old question but I wanted to comment that I faced the exact same formatting issue. That format is the ISO 8601 format, which is a pretty standard format.

Comment: thank you for the answer to the extra : in the timezone.  I was getting a timezone from a google rss feed that had -04:00 and it was driving me crazy for hours.  Your solution to change the tz to -0400 was the trick.

Comment: This is not the most optimal solution anymore. See my answer below.

Comment: Note: Use lowercase 'z' to get just the timezone string (e.g. `zzz` -> `EDT`)

Answer (score 64):

To process the time zone with the colon in it, you just need to use 5 'Z's. This is a pretty common date format, the ISO-8601 format. This will only work on iOS 6.x+

```
-(NSDate *) dateFromString:(NSString *)string {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

    return [formatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

Comment: Confirmed that this is a better solution than the accepted answer!

Comment: Works on iOS6.0+ but not on 5.0 or 5.1

Comment: yes 5 Z's works - heres a category

https://github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601

Comment: This didn't work for me (2016-04-04T00:00:00-5:00), however this did- yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ:z

Answer (score 3):

May be I missed something but `ZZ` worked for me.
I used:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
```

for

```
2014-02-27T08:00:00.000+04:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default time format I got from a Sinatra ActiveRecord backend.  Here is my solution.

```
-(NSDate *) dateFromString:(NSString *)string{
    NSMutableString * correctedDateString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    [correctedDateString deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(22, 1)];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

    return [formatter dateFromString:correctedDateString];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

Answer (score 0):

5 ZZZZZ - heres a category I wrote with some sample of GMT to BST

https://github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601