# NSDateFormatter not recognizing timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this date:

```
2013-07-15T06:07:53-04:00
```

I use NSDateFormatter to convert this to NSDate:

```
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

This works but it doesn't recognize the timezone. It returns:

```
2013-07-15 10:07:53 +0000
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: where r u setting the timezone?

Comment: @Kasaname not explicitly setting any timezone. Isn't the date formatter suppose to get it from the date string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log output is correct. `NSLog`ging an `NSDate` will always show that date/time in UTC (see how your output has `+0000` instead of `-04:00`). `NSDate` objects represent a specific moment in time regardless of calendar and timezones. You use this "moment in time" in conjunction with a formatter (with a timezone set) in order to format that "moment in time" into a locale-specific time.

If you want to see log the output with your own timezone:

```
// pick a different timezone if necessary
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:momentInTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```

Comment: this doesnot work . the format is wrong and if u use it it will give a null valuye

Answer (score 0):

isn't the "-04:00" at the end of the string telling NSDateFormatter that this date is GMT-4 and thus, it's just converting it to GMT ?

If not, please provide the full initialization of your NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

more info here

[iPhone NSDateFormatter Timezone Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094730/iphone-nsdateformatter-timezone-conversion/22173085#22173085)

5 ZZZZZ - heres a category I wrote with some sample of GMT to BST

https://github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601