# Ruby formatted date to NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, time, swift2, nsdate, datetime-format

How can I turn `2016-07-05 22:13:48 +0000` into an `NSDate`? I don't know which format is to used, I have no idea what the +0000 is for. Is there any convenient way to to use that input string directly to make an `NSDate` object in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone NSDateFormatter Timezone Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094730/iphone-nsdateformatter-timezone-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` like this.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-07-05 22:13:48 +0000")
print("Date is - \(date)")
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Here date is `NSDate` object.

Comment: Also +0000 is used with timezone hour specification and its formatter is `z/Z` . For more detail about formatter check this link http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/, Check the zone section in the link.